# dark shadow on nav header after fragment transaction

Tags: android

When I am navigating back & forth between two fragments, i see a dark shadow on the top of nav header. How can I get rid of it?

Before Navigating

[image]

After Navigating

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with this..

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
.......
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
...>
```